# In MVC is it possible to override an editor template

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

is it possible to override an editor template?

I have DateTime fields in my model, which are used for arrival/departure dates - and these are rendered using the following EditorTemplate:

```
@model Nullable<System.DateTime> 

@if ( Model.HasValue ) { 
   @Html.TextBox( "" , String.Format( "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" , Model.Value ) , new  { @class = "datepicker span2" } ) 
} 
else { 
   @Html.TextBox( "" , String.Format( "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" , DateTime.Now ) , new { @class = "datepicker span2" } ) 
}
```

...which will format datetime fields eg: 01/08/2012

However, I also want to show, in another field, the date AND time a booking was made eg:

```
22/07/2012 08:23
```

My model is:

```
    public DateTime Arrival { get; set; }
    public DateTime Departure { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeBooked { get; set; }
```

I would like TimeBooked to show time as well - but the Editor Template obviously just shows the date.

Can this be overridden?  Or is there another way of doing this?

Thank you,

Mark

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can add a different named editor which shows time also and use an overload of EditorFor, which accepts template name as second parameter, like:

EditorFor(m=>m.TimeBooked, "DateWithTimeTemplate")

[MSDN help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee407414.aspx)

Comment: Please remember that the partial view should be in Shared/EditorTemplates/  for it to work

Answer (score 4):

You can by using the [UIHintAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.uihintattribute.aspx) attribute.
You can decorate the `TimeBooked` property with this attribute so MVC will know which editor to use.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that by adding the `hh:mm` placeholder..

```
String.Format("{0:d/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss}", DateTime.Now)
```

For more examples, see [here](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/)..

Comment: That's not the question he asked. That's how the two editor templates will be different, he asked how he could use two editor templates in the first place.