# Override ASP.NET MVC EditorFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to override ASP.NET MVC's `EditorFor` and `DisplayFor`.

I want to apply some logic as to whether or not to actually display the content or simply output "".

So I want to do something like this (pseudocode):

```
public static MyEditorFor(this html)
{
  if(ICanRender)
  {
    call HtmlEditorFor(original);
  }
  else
  {
    return EmtpyString;
  }
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In MVC is it possible to override an editor template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11599204/in-mvc-is-it-possible-to-override-an-editor-template)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by _override_, but you can create your own Display and Editor templates that will be used by those methods to render whatever you want

Comment: I disagree, it does not show any solution for what I require in that question.  I Don't want to supply a different template.  I want to put logic in that question suggests adding a different named template

Comment: You can also create your own helper method as override of `EditorFor` or `DisplayFor` if you wish to do

Comment: @AdilMammadov that is exactly what I want to do.  How can I do that and in an extension method?

Comment: I am writing it as answer shortly

Comment: I don't know the syntax to call editor or displayfor programmatically.

Comment: @AdilMammadov thank you sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sound like you want an extension:

```
public static MvcHtmlString MyEditorFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression) {
    if(ICanRender)
    {
        return System.Web.Mvc.Html.EditorExtensions.EditorFor(html, expression);
    }
    else
    {
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(string.Empty);
    }
}
```

That codesnipped is untested but it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own Html helpers as extensions methods for `HtmlHelper` or `HtmlHelper<TModel>`. Simply add extension method like below:

```
public static MvcHtmlString MyEditorFor<TModel, TProperty>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
{

}
```

Of course, you can add additional parameters as needed. Inside this method access all methods of `htmlHelper`. Return ordinary `EditorFor` for example:

```
public static MvcHtmlString MyEditorFor<TModel, TProperty>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
{
    return htmlHelper.EditorFor(expression);
}
```

Or you can create your own element (or combination of them) as you need:

```
public static MvcHtmlString MyEditorFor<TModel, TProperty>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
{
    TagBuilder div = new TagBuilder("div");
    div.AddCssClass("some-css");

    MvcHtmlString editor = htmlHelper.TextBoxFor(expression);
    div.InnerHtml = editor.ToHtmlString();

    return new MvcHtmlString(div.ToString());
}
```

Read more about `TagBuilder` [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.tagbuilder(v=vs.111).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You could put the custon models under the "views/shared/EditorTemplates" or "views/shared/DisplayTemplates", and put the files with the [Model name].cshtml.

Ex: DateTime.cshtml

That way all editors and displays with DateTime type defined in your models properties will follow the DateTime.cshtml logic.

The problem is you will have to deal with the HTML in the ViewData.TemplateInfo if you want to retrieve the fields you want.